Typescript infers type never on Union of two types
In the following example, in the getAdditionalData function, Typescript infers the type of value to never after validating the type through isBarType. I would expect the type to be FooEntity since Entity can be either FooEntity OR BarEntity.
Why is that the case?
I'm aware I can avoid the problematic by doing the opposite validation, i.e. if(isFooType(value)) { return value.additionalData;} but I'm interested to know why Typescript behaves like this.
Link to TS Playground
type BaseEntity = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
}

type FooEntity = BaseEntity & {
    additionalData: string,
}

type BarEntity = BaseEntity & {};

type Entity = FooEntity | BarEntity;

function isFooType(value: Entity): value is FooEntity {
    return value.name === 'foo';
}

function isBarType(value: Entity): value is BarEntity {
    return value.name === 'bar';
}

function getAdditionalData(value: Entity): string {
    if(isBarType(value)) {
        return '';
    }

    // Property 'additionalData' does not exist on type 'never'
    return value.additionalData;
}


type BaseEntity = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
}

type FooEntity = BaseEntity & {
    additionalData: string,
}

type BarEntity = BaseEntity & {};

type Entity = FooEntity | BarEntity;

Let's expand this to the resulting types. This is what Entity resolves to.
type Entity =
  | { // FooEntity
      id: string;
      name: string;
      additionalData: string;
    }
  | { // BarEntity
      id: string;
      name: string;
    };

Here FooEntity is assignable to a BarEntity because FooEntity has every property that is required by BarEntity. This means that both sides of the union are valid BarEntity types.
So when you do:
    if(isBarType(value)) {
        return '';
    }

You are saying, if this value is a bar type, then early return. But all members of the union are valid BarEntity types. And if it's not a BarEntity then it cannot be a FooEntity, since all FooEntity's are also BarEntity's.
So all parts of the union that match BarEntity are excluded, which is all members of the union since they all match, and so the result is that that it narrows to never.

Put another way:
type FooEntity = {
    a: boolean,
}

type BarEntity = {
    a: boolean
    b: boolean
}

type Entity = FooEntity | BarEntity;

type MyNarrowedEntity = Exclude<Entity, { a: boolean }> // never

Here we exclude an object type that all union members match to, which elminates all members of that union, and the result is never.
This is basically what the type is narrowing doing for you.

You probably want a discriminated union:
type BaseEntity = {
    id: string,
    name: string,
}

type FooEntity = BaseEntity & {
    name: 'foo',
    additionalData: string,
}

type BarEntity = BaseEntity & {
    name: 'bar',
};

type Entity = FooEntity | BarEntity;

Now BarEntity is not assignable to FooEntity because the name is different. Then your code works as expected.
See playground

do you know in this case if its correct to say that FooEntity is a subtype of BaseEntity and therefore BarEntity, as in it's always assignable because just has extra properties. That's how I was thinking about this but don't know if that term works for typescript?

Yeah, that's technically correct. But I do find that language of "subtype" confusing with object types because it's not intuitive that { a: 1, b: 2 } is a subtype of { a: 1 }, but it makes sense that it is assignable. While it is more intuitive that 'a' is a subtype of string. The way typescript works, those really are the same concept though.

With object types, it's like saying that a house is a subtype of an empty room with toilet, because a house has a toilet. But if all you need is a place with a toilet, then a house with a toilet will be perfectly acceptable.

yea nice, makes sense, guess seems not so intuitive when you give examples like that ahaha but correct, I was thinking how to formalize the situation outlined in the question, if its that control flow with typeguard are on supertype of all union members so it narrows type to never.
